# NLP - Error while Tokenization and Tagging etc

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to identify all the Tokens and also PartsOfSpeech Tagging using the Stanford NLP jar file. I have added all the required jar files into the build path of the project..The error which I am getting is..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at Test.testing(Test.java:19)
    at mainFunction.main(mainFunction.java:29)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to use Stanford NLP tools version 3.5 or later using a version of Java 7 or earlier.  Either upgrade to Java 8 or downgrade to Stanford tools version 3.4.1.

Comment: i have same problem here . i have java 6 . what will appropraite verison of stanford should i have ?

Comment: 3.4.1. See the table here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html